# Text Analytics/ Text prediction approach in python

Tags: python, text, prediction, text-analysis

This is my  customer dataset

```
ID    Address                    Location    Age
1    room no5,
     rose apt,hill street,       Nagpur      38
     nagpur-"500249"      
2    block C-4,kirti park,       Thane       26
     Thane-"400356"
3    Dream villa, noor nagar,                46
     Colaba-"400008" 
5    Sita Apt,Room no 101,       Kalyan      55
     Kalyan- "421509"
7    Rose Apt, room no 20,       Mumbai      43
     Antop hill, 
     Mumbai-"400007"
8   Dirk Villa,nouis park,       Mumbai      50
    Dadar-"400079"
9   Raj apt,room no-2,                       33
    powai,"400076"
```

As in above case I have **Address column** values and corresponding values for **Location column**. Now given the above training data(data which will have all Address and Location values present) and test data( data which will consist only Address values for which I would be wanting to predict Location for it) I want to forecast which Address will fall under what loaction.
For this problem I want to know which approach in **Python** would suit the best,here are some reference which I had came across, but do not know which to follow.
here are some links[link_1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

[link_2](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/10/understaing-support-vector-machine-example-code/)
Any suggestion will be much more appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Its not about "Python" here, Its about finding the right Algorithm and then comes a Language. Its a very broad question. There are no silver bullets. My friend, there is no apply "Binary Search" kind of solution here. However you might not require any Machine Learning and simple rules might work for you, for example, If you are looking at only Indian addresses and if there are pin codes, why dont you download pin code directory from https://data.gov.in/catalog/all-india-pincode-directory? Supervised Machine Learning (this is what you are looking at, in those links) wont work for your use case.

Comment: Alright @Yavar this solution might be a go through for me...Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Those pin codes are always included in the addresses and you want to find the associated city or other geographical entity?

Comment: Having downloaded `all_india_pin_code.csv` I notice that PIN 500249 (in the first record) doesn't exist. Can you assume that all, or most, of the PINs in the customer's dataset will be correct and that they exist?